# I'm new to making a discord bot with python, and I'm having trouble with it. I send "$hello" to get a response, but nothing happens

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, I'm using replit.com to make the bot, and the bot comes online just fine. I type in $hello and expect to get a response saying "Commander". I do that, but the bot doesn't reply back. I based this script off a [video on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPTfmiYiuok&t=2031s). I'm guessing it could be something to do with my code, or the discord bot permissions. Any help/ advice would be appreciated, thanks.

```
import discord
import os
import time 

client = discord.Client()

@client.event 
async def on_ready():
  print('We have broken into american server farms as {0.user}'.format(client))
  time.sleep(1)
  print("Accessing private data...")
  time.sleep(2)
  print("Installing malware...")
  time.sleep(2)
  print("Extracting stolen files...")
  time.sleep(2)
  print("Finishing up..")
  time.sleep(1)
  print("All objectives completed, State Messenger Bot is now online.")


  @client.event
  async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
      return 

      if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Commander')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `time.sleep` within asynchronous code, use `await asyncio.sleep(n)` instead. *PS: That second if statement should be at the same level of indentation as the first one, not inside of it.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand the question but I will try to answer it

```
import discord

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("we have powered on, I an alive.")

@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Commander')

client.run('TOKEN')
```

What the last part does is wait until someone says $hello and then replies Commander. The prefix has been defined at the start so you do not need to define a prefix for every command. In `async def hello(ctx):` you can change hello to be the name of your command

Comment: I see, thanks a lot as it helps and I didn't know until now. What I'm trying to ask is why the commands do not work when I input them in a discord text channel.

Comment: Can I recommend you watch an easy tutorial to start off where they explain things better [This one works but is a bit outdated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nW8c7vT6Hl4&list=PLW3GfRiBCHOhfVoiDZpSz8SM_HybXRPzZ)  or [This one is newer but full disclosure I made it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDKmb03lc0o&list=PLib_mf4mWkKUm7YVzeNvPv1wP2eI4KtRK) @Dusco_11

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. I appreciate the help